# In Krita, how to change all instances of a specific colour to another specific colour?

Tags: colors, krita

For example, let's say I want to change all instances of RGB #FF0000 to RGB #FF8888. I have read the [manual entry on the Similar Colour Selection tool](https://docs.krita.org/en/reference_manual/tools/similar_select.html), but this doesn't say how to effect the change.